# How to change Toolkit in Linux Mint to GTK

Tags: linux-mint, gtk, qt

I recently purged KDE from my Linux Mint 17.3 KDE edition and installed Cinnamon.

I was able to upgrade it to version 18 (Sarah) Cinnamon. Yes, despite it is KDE edition. There were problems, but I was able to solve them.

```
cat /etc/linuxmint/info
```

now says

```
RELEASE=18
CODENAME=sarah
EDITION="Cinnamon 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 Sarah"
DESKTOP=KDE
TOOLKIT=QT
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_kde_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_kde.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=`yelp help:linuxmint`
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit
```

Note, that I changed KDE edition to Cinnamon here. But that is less important.

**What interests me is what is TOOLKIT=QT? And how do I change it to GTK?**

Comment: Some useful info here: https://github.com/linuxmint/gtk